# How to retrieve gender of my friends with facepy?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facepy

When I try to make this fql:

```
print graph.fql('SELECT name FROM user WHERE gender =male ')
```

I got this error :

```
OAuthError: [602] (#602) gender is not a member of the user table.
```

And I have added them in friends data  permissions.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this using the Graph API
`flist=graph.get('me/friends?fields=gender')`

If you want only FQL, do this:
`graph.fql('SELECT gender FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())')`

I implemented this a few days back and you can check the source code here: https://github.com/astronomersiva/Facebook-analysers/blob/master/Gender%20analyser.py